# JScrollPane can resize smaller, but JTextArea does not

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane, jtextarea

I have a window containing a JScrollArea, which contains a JPanel which contains a JTextArea.  When I resize the window to make it larger, the layout updates perfectly, but if I make the window smaller, the JPanel does not shrink its contents.  I attempted to add a ComponentListener on the JScrollArea to resize the JPanel based on the new size of the viewport, but this seems to defeat the purpose of the vertical scroll bar.

UPDATE: The idea here is that the JScrollArea will contain a JPanel (since it can only contain one component for its viewport), and within that JPanel I will be adding multiple JPanels containing components that describe processes that are running to the user.  Since there could be any number of these processes running, I need to have some kind of scroll bar functionality available.  Hence the component hierarchy I'm using below.

The desired behavior here is that the window can be resized larger or smaller and the text area will wrap its contents accordingly, and a vertical scroll bar will appear if the contents of the JPanel are larger vertically than the window.  Any suggestions?

```
public class TestWindow extends JFrame {
    JPanel scrollContentPanel;
    JScrollPane scrollPane;

    public TestWindow() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        this.setContentPane(mainPanel);
        GridBagLayout mainPanelLayout = new GridBagLayout();
        mainPanel.setLayout(mainPanelLayout);

        scrollContentPanel = new JPanel();
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setViewportView(scrollContentPanel);
        scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        GridBagLayout scrollContentLayout = new GridBagLayout();
        scrollContentPanel.setLayout(scrollContentLayout);

        JPanel contentEntry = new JPanel();
        GridBagConstraints contentEntryConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        contentEntryConstraints.weightx = 1.0;
        contentEntryConstraints.insets = new Insets(3, 3, 5, 3);
        contentEntryConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        contentEntryConstraints.gridx = 0;
        contentEntryConstraints.gridy = 1;
        scrollContentPanel.add(contentEntry, contentEntryConstraints);
        GridBagLayout contentEntryLayout = new GridBagLayout();
        contentEntry.setLayout(contentEntryLayout);

        JTextArea descTextArea = new JTextArea();
        descTextArea.setEditable(false);
        descTextArea.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 11));
        descTextArea.setText("This is a description of an arbitrary unspecified length that may easily span multiple lines without any breaks in-between.  Therefore it is necessary that the description automatically wrap as appropriate.");
        descTextArea.setLineWrap(true);
        descTextArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        GridBagConstraints descTextAreaConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        descTextAreaConstraints.weightx = 1.0;
        descTextAreaConstraints.weighty = 1.0;
        descTextAreaConstraints.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 3, 0);
        descTextAreaConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        descTextAreaConstraints.gridx = 0;
        descTextAreaConstraints.gridy = 1;
        descTextAreaConstraints.gridwidth = 2;
        contentEntry.add(descTextArea, descTextAreaConstraints);
        GridBagConstraints scrollPaneConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        scrollPaneConstraints.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
        scrollPaneConstraints.weightx = 1.0;
        scrollPaneConstraints.weighty = 1.0;
        scrollPaneConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        scrollPaneConstraints.gridx = 0;
        scrollPaneConstraints.gridy = 0;
        mainPanel.add(scrollPane, scrollPaneConstraints);

        scrollPane.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent evt) {
                super.componentResized(evt);

                scrollContentPanel.setPreferredSize(scrollPane.getViewportBorderBounds().getSize());
                scrollContentPanel.validate();
            }
        });

        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestWindow wnd = new TestWindow();
        wnd.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JTextArea` should be placed directly into the `JScrollPane`, as long as that is the component your are trying to scroll.  If there are other items you want to scroll with it (and hence the intermediate `JPanel`), then you might want to consider making that `JPanel` implement `Scrollable` so that the `JScrollPane` knows what to do with it.  `JTextArea` implements `Scrollable`, which is why it works with `JScrollPane` out of the box.

Answer (score 3):

- no idea about your goal without detailed description, explanation
- `JTextArea` should be placed in `JScrollPane`
- set intial `setPreferredSize` for `JTextArea`, e.g. `JTextArea(5, 10)`
- you are put three `JPanels` (is there reason ??? for this components hierarchy) one to `JScrollPane`, `JTextArea` is placed directly into `JPanel` instead of to the `JScrollPane`
- then usage of `ComponentListener` is useless and contraproductive

Comment: Added some explanation for the component hierarchy in the question.